# Is it wrong to save fragment state using show/hide transactions?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bottomnavigationview, fragmenttransaction

I have a bottomNavigationView with five tabs that navigate the user between five fragments. I want the state of four of them to be saved at a time, Like when user goes to fragment B and returns to fragment A, then fragment A should be exactly the same as he left it. First, I used android navigation components but It doesn't support multiple stacks, so I removed it and used the popular fragment transactions.

Here is what I am currently doing :

- I have a memeber variable 'activeFragment' in my activity, that is initialized to be the main fragment the user sees on entering the activity, and updated when user navigates to another fragment
- When user navigates to a fragment, I hide the current active fragment and show the fragment associated with clicked tab(If that fragment wasn't already created, I gets created first) using :

  ```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(activeFragment).show(toFragment);
  ```

It works just fine, the only weird behavior is that fragments don't receive usual lifecycle callbacks, like when I navigate to a fragment It doesn't trigger onResume , when I press home button and return to the activity, all the fragments receive 'onResume' which is kind of awkward.

So, Is this the a safe approach to go about it ? Is there a better way to do that ? Why on earth does android not have an out of the box way to do this, given the many apps that implement this feature, even their google play store app implements it ?

Edit :
This is how I am navigating between fragments :

```
    private void moveToFragment(MenuItem fragmentNavItem) {
    //Get toFragment given its id
    int id = fragmentNavItem.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    String tag = getFragmentTagFromItemId(id);
    Fragment toFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.hide(activeFragment);
    if (toFragment == null) {
        //We go to this fragment for the first time
        toFragment = createFragmentFromItemId(id);
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_main, toFragment, tag);
    } else {
        //We have been in this fragment before
        transaction.show(toFragment);
    }

    transaction.commit();

    activeFragment = toFragment;
    toolbar.setTitle(fragmentNavItem.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: you need to override onBackPressed in your activity

Comment: show the main code and we will see what can be done

Comment: There is the code, I am not using the back stack functionality to override onBackPressed

Comment: I am actually overrideing onBackPressed to get back to main fragment, otherwise exit the app, but this is not of main interest right now, I wan to know if using show/hide is a good approach or not ?

Comment: you can try in your fragmentTransaction after " transaction.add.." set this ".addToBackStack(null)" try it

Comment: Then, how can I pop a specific fragment from the stack, that's not supported

Comment: `hide` is pretty crude, it just makes the view invisible so it keeps all lifecycles and observers up to keep it up to date for when you make it visible again. In my projects I use `detach`/`attach` instead which destroys only the view hierarchy while keeping all fields untouched and forces fragment into stopped state.

Comment: Well, I tried to use detach/attach but there is a weird behavior, I have a viewpager in one of the fragments and It acts kind of weird

Comment: Here is a pic of what the viewpager is like, content fragments disappear, and tabs are switching is not working right, it gets such between two tabs https://ibb.co/jw7NswY

Comment: If you need a multistack, you can check https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/tree/8adfe49918ddf76c8d6eba7d31aba510afeba1b7/samples/multistack-samples/simple-stack-example-multistack-fragment/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackdemomultistack and see if it helps, otherwise if your ViewPager fragments disappear, you used `fragmentManager` instead of `childFragmentManager` for your adapter

Answer (score 0):

It good approach only if it is safe for memory to store your 5 fragments at once.

For managing lifecycle you can use FragmentTransaction.setMaxLifecycle()

for example:

```
  fragmentManager
      .beginTransaction()
      .run {
          fragmentManager
              .fragments
              .forEach {
                  hide(it)
                  setMaxLifecycle(it, Lifecycle.State.CREATED)
               }
                    
           show(topFragment)
           setMaxLifecycle(topFragment, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
         }
      .commit()
```